# Maximum open security on NFS export of shared directory

Tags: nfs, kubernetes

I have a huge problem with Kubernetes and permission problems with PVCs.

Here's my NFS export line:

```
/srv/nfs4           192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,fsid=0)

/srv/nfs4/k8s                   192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash)
```

Here's the directory in an ls.

```
david@dell-nfs:/srv/nfs4$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  8 root             root             4096 Sep 14 19:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root             root             4096 Aug  9 15:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 root             systemd-coredump 4096 Oct 20 15:58 k8s
```

My issue is that I am using a dynamic PVC provisioner (creates unique folders in NFS share like so:

```
david@dell-nfs:/srv/nfs4/k8s$ ls -la
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  systemd-coredump 4096 Oct 20 15:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  root             4096 Sep 14 19:08 ..
drwxrwxrwx  3 david david            4096 Oct 20 15:53 pvc-5384721a-0ab7-435c-9cac-22183861b5c5
drwxrwxrwx  3  1001 systemd-coredump 4096 Oct 20 15:40 pvc-55df0dda-5ed5-4f6d-9979-41b53c451bea
drwxrwxrwx 14 root  root             4096 Oct 20 15:49 pvc-7fc0e511-f2fe-4cde-bfff-589728f219c5
drwxrwxrwx  3 david david            4096 Oct 20 15:53 pvc-87e83254-9c86-4df9-a1bd-fc4cbdd90bcd
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  root             4096 Oct 20 15:49 pvc-9aa60ede-8e5a-463d-a5f4-ce07d9019203
```

But, as the PVCs are being created with my Kubernetes provisioning, the using Pods get permission denied adding content to the unique folders. I have modified one Helm installation and relaxed security and things worked. To provision my entire cluster here on bare-metal, I have `chmod -R 777` each unique PVC directory during the Ansible installation. I know this is wrong.

My question is: Have I done everything I can do on the NFS/Linux side of things to help with this situation? I am working from home and our Cluster and Tech-Stack are being installed on AWS, GCE, and Azure. I'm an architect and using NFS as my EDS (AWS Persistence) e.g. So I would like to know if I've done everything I can do to relax the security on my NFS server?

P.S. My next research will have to be with Kubernetes and Ansible role installations for each tech-stack item. My dynamic-NFS-provisioner works great, but if the Pods on startup, can't write to my single NFS share, then I'm hosed.